# How to change a column data type in excel based on the column header using powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a spreadsheet that has 5 columns: Application_Name, Executive, Last_Update, Application_Cost, Owner. I would like to be able to read the worksheet and assign the data types based on the column header. I know how do it using a range:

`$sheet.Range("C:C").NumberFormat = "mm-dd-yyyy"`

Instead I am looking for a code that would read the column headers and do something like this.

```
$sheet.Header("Application_Name").NumberFormat = "General"
$sheet.Header("Last_Update").NumberFormat = "mm-dd-yyyy"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is an easier way, but you could create a lookup Hashtable with the column names and their indices:

```
$colMax = $sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
$headers = @{}
for ($col = 1; $col -le $colMax; $col++) {
    $name = $sheet.Cells.Item(1, $col).Value()  # assuming the first row has the headers
    $headers[$name] = $col
}
```

Then, you could get the columns index by its name using this lookuptable

```
$headers['Last_Update'] --> 3
```

and use like:

```
$sheet.Columns($headers['Application_Name']).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "General"
$sheet.Columns($headers['Last_Update']).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "mm-dd-yyyy"
```

Hope that helps.

<sup>The NumberFormat names are LOCALIZED in Excel. Please first check what language your copy uses. (For instance, in a Dutch system, "General" is "Standaard" and "yyyy" is "jjjj"). Terrible, I know, but thats'how it is unfortunately..</sup>